# How to get text from input box to a span

Tags: javascript, html

I have got the HTML but I am not sure on how to get the input box into the span.
I tried using `document.getElementById` but that didn't work. Any help would be great!

```
Name:
<p>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
<p>
  <button id= "button" onclick="namejs">Go</button>
<p>
  <span id= "namespan">Name</span>
```

Comment: Presumably you want to do this in response to a click on the button? What is the `namejs` in your button's `onclick`?

Comment: are you using plain javascript or jquery

Comment: @R4nc1d javascript

Comment: @hamish, ok cool you can look at my answer then. I also added and fiddle for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, this is plain `Javascript`
Getting values you can use

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="value";
```

For modern browsers

```
document.getElementById("myspan").textContent="value";
```

**CODE**

```
Name:
<p>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
  <p>
<button id= "button" onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>
  <p>
  <span id="namespan">Name</span>

function myFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById("namespan").textContent=name;
}
```

Added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwoq052j/)

Answer (score 1):

You can user innerHTML attribute for span tag, like below :

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value; //get name from TextBox
document.getElementById("namespan").innerHTML=name ; //write in span
```

Comment: Almost. You should do `...innerHTML=name.value` in the assignment though.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
            document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
<label>Your input: </label>
<p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **[jquery](https://jquery.com/)** , you can **smoothly** update `span` on real-time when you write in `input` :

```
$('#namespan').html($('#name').val()); // GET Value of INPUT --> SET IT as inner HTML of span
```

---

## DEMO :

```js
$('#name').keyup(function(){
      $('#namespan').html($(this).val()); // GET Value of INPUT --> SET IT as inner HTML of span
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name:
<p>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
  </p>
<p>
  <button id= "button" onclick="namejs">Go</button>
  </p>
<p>
  <span id= "namespan">Name</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onkeyup` event handler

```js
document.getElementById('name').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('namespan').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
Name:
<p>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
</p>
<p>
  <button id="button" onclick="namejs">Go</button>
</p>
<p>
  <span id="namespan">Name</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

**Html:**

```
Name:
<p><input type="text" name="fname" id="name"><p>
<p><button id= "button">Go</button></p>
<p><span id= "namespan">Name</span></p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$('#namespan').text($('#name').val()); 
});
```